# Jquery оборачивание результата в [] после when

Tags: jquery, ajax

Нужно создать массив после получения аякс

1 вариант

```
var q1 = $.ajax({
    url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    }
}).then(q1)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
```

получаю

```
[Object { name="ч1",  num="33"}, Object { name="ч2",  num="22"}]
```

2 вариант

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var q1 = $.ajax({
        url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    var q2 = $.ajax({
        url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech2",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    var q = $.when(q1, q2)
            .then(function (data, data2) {
               console.log(data)
```

Вывод:

```
[[Object { name="ч1",  num="33"}, Object { name="ч2",  num="22"}], "success", Object { readyState=4,  responseText="[{"name":"\u04e\u04b\u...","num":"33"}]",  status=200,  ещё...}]
```

почему разные форматы ответа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это особенность функции `when`: каждый параметр, который пробрасывается в функцию `then` - это, чем разрешилось конкретное обещание.

Если чуть модифицировать первый вариант, можно увидеть, что результаты совпадают:

```
var q1 = $.ajax({
    url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    }
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(arguments)
});
```

Чтобы в `when` тоже получать *только* первый параметр, нужно добавить `then` к объявлениям запросов:

```
var q1 = $.ajax({
    url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
}).then(function(data){ return data;});
var q2 = $.ajax({
    url: "php/sms_sender.php?act=get_tech2",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
}).then(function(data){ return data;});
```

Теперь после выполнения `when` так же выведется

```
[Object { name="ч1",  num="33"}, Object { name="ч2",  num="22"}]
```